# What statistical metrics / tools can be used to quantify underestimation of uncertainties in distances to astronomical objects?

Tags: standard-error, error, measurement-error, error-propagation, type-i-and-ii-errors

Amazingly low uncertainties are frequently reported in distances to astronomical objects. However, the uncertain region of the measurements frequently fail to overlap.

Is there a statistical measure / tool that can help me quantify the and/or determine that the uncertainties were underestimated?

In other words, what statistical metrics or tools can be used to emphasize and quantify the error in the estimation of uncertainties?

Comment: before tools can be recommendee, some context is needed as to what the experiment is and what the measure is

Comment: @develarist Thank you for your comment. I wanted a general introduction to metrics useful for quantifying error in estimation. However, if specifics are important, I am primarily interested in distance data of astronomical objects.

Comment: @develarist I have edited the question to add clarity as per your instructions. Thank you for your guidance 

Comment: It would help if you could give some specific examples of this phenomenon, with web links, as I suspect that few who visit this site are familiar with astronomical measurements. You might get a more informed answer at https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EdM The reason I didn't post it on Astronomy SE is that it is a relatively quiet community with even many of my good questions not eliciting a response (for example: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/what-error-bar-confidence-level-is-generally-reported-in-galaxy-distances). I will try to find some good examples and post them here.

Comment: @RiteshSingh By "the uncertain region of the measurements frequently fail to overlap" do you mean that there are different measurements that are inconsistent among each other?

Comment: @Albercoc Correct sir/madam, that would be another way to say the same thing.