# Is this way of calculating the chi-squared value correct?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, p-value

I have read that the chi-squared value is calculated as follows:

$$\chi^2 = \sum \frac{(\text{observed value} - \text{expected value})^2}{\text{(expected value)}}$$

However, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57326/135885) mentions it as:

$$\chi^2 = \sum \frac{(\text{observed value} - \text{true value})^2}{\text{(uncertainty associated with that observation)}^2}$$

Is it correct? Are the two equivalent? If so, how?

Comment: @Alexis Thank you for your comment. Edited as per your instructions.

Comment: Also: Welcome to CV, Ritesh Singh.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you, have a great weekend :)

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this question, I have always understood that the division by $\text{expected value}_{ij}$ was to normalize the size of the deviances in the numerator to a commensurate scale across all cells/values of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: If about contingency table tests: There is some glossing over the fact that the sum is hiding a double summation: $\chi^2 = \frac{\sum_{i}^{\text{# rows}}\sum_{j}^{\text{# cols}}\left(\text{observed value}_{ij} - \text{expected value}_{ij}\right)^{2}}{\text{expected value}_{ij}}$.

Comment: @Alexis I changed the second formula to directly quote the linked site, as that's important for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a lot of confusion about $\chi^2$ tests, as they appear in any application that involves sums of independent normally distributed random variables. The first version is the standard test for a contingency table or similar comparisons of known against expected values.

The second version seems to be an application of [minimum chi-square estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_chi-square_estimation), compounded with a bit of confusion in the terminology. The "observed" values are those of a set of observations each with a different error estimate. In [this application](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57326):

> You numerically choose the "true value" that minimizes $\chi^2$. That's your best guess.

Thus each numerator term is related to an estimate of the variance of the observations about the (estimated, "true") mean.

Each denominator term, the square of the "uncertainty associated with that observation," is proportional to an estimate of the variance of the individual observation. So this procedure is equivalent to minimizing an inverse-variance-weighted mean-square error.

As best as I can tell, the further calculation of the $\chi^2$ statistic is to test whether the inverse-variance-weighted sum of deviations from the mean is consistent with a [sum of independent normally distributed differences from the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Sum_of_squares_of_i.i.d_normals_minus_their_mean).

Comment: Thank you! Clearly, you can see much deeper than me. If/when free, could you please also answer my other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485113/what-statistical-metrics-tools-can-be-used-to-quantify-underestimation-of-unce. That was my original question and I stumbled upon this Physics SE answer while scouring for answer to it. In particular, my question is: Is the method given in the Physics SE answer a valid method to estimate error in uncertainties (from the p value of the chi-squared calculated as given there)?

Comment: @RiteshSingh that is an extremely broad question that encompasses much of metrology and statistics. Answering it would require a lot of information about the nature of the what's being measured, the "true" variation in the values being measured, the measurement methods and their systematic and random errors, and so on. It's hard to give a useful answer to such a broad question; the more specific you can make it, the better.

Comment: I have edited the question to add clarity as per your instructions. Please do have a look if/when free: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485113/what-statistical-metrics-tools-can-be-used-to-quantify-underestimation-of-unce. Thank you for your time and guidance.